# How can I select an element by classname in another page?

Tags: jquery

I have a site called site.com and I want to check if the `classname` is present on my other page http://site.com/subfolder and if it is yes then perform the code.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    if ($('http://site.com/subfolder classname').length > 0) {
        $('.headline').after('<div>text</div>');
    }
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You would have to perform an ajax request to get the html, then search for your element within that html.

Comment: That cannot be done in a way you are expecting...

Comment: Do you mean css class of an element on another page?

Comment: I would suggest that there's something horribly wrong with the overall approach if you need to test for the presence of something on a different page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you own the site I consider that you shouldn't be doing this.

But, if you still insist you may use something along these lines:

```
$("<div/>").load("http://site.com/subfolder .classname", function(){
  if(this.children.length){
    $('.headline').after('<div>text</div>');
  }
});
```

I am abusing of [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)'s page fragment loading.

Comment: Nice. Getting jQuery to parse the matching element is much easier. However, if the element doesn't have any children, `this.children.length` returns 0 which evaluates to false.

Answer (score 0):

When the document finishes loading, use jQuery to issue a request for the second page, then check the result for your classname. The following snippet will check if classname appears anywhere in the markup for the page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get('subfolder', function(data) {
        if (data.indexOf('classname') != -1){
            $('.headline').after('<div>text</div>');
        }
    });
 )};
```

Note indexOf is case-sensitive. This particular snippet will find a match if classname appears anywhere in the markup of the page in subfolder.